# How to predict the "when" and "why" of hospital admission?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, predictive-models, medicine

I already posted in another [FORUM](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88865/how-to-predict-when-and-why-of-hospitalization) but no response. So, posting it here in CV

I have a database that has info on

- a) Patient visit records (Inpatient, outpatient, Emergency, etc) and why did he visit the hospital (diagnosis codes attached to each visit)
- b) Patients drugs data
- c) Patients lab test data
- d) Patient diagnosis history
- e) Patient demographics data

If my objective had just been to predict when will the patient's next hospitalization be, I can use Time to event analysis or survival analysis, etc.

But, I would also like to know why will he visit the hospital next, or what might be the reason for his next hospital visit?

example use case : Patient 123's next hospital date is 90% likely to be 21st Jan 2021 with 70% likelihood of eye complication due to diabetes and 50% likelihood of disease B and 30% likelihood of disease C

While predicting "when" seems to be doable, can experts here guide me on how can I find why/what (along with "when") will be the reason for his next hospital visit?

Comment: You could use Cox survival analysis with regressors which could associate “why/what” some of the factors that are driving hospital admissions. As an example of patient has diabetes then you can associate(not associate) this to hospital admission.

Comment: Please add that to the post as an edit! Not everybody reads comments! And then consider add more information. Looks like an ambitious project, like predicting what other health problems a person might have not yet detected. How big is the database, what is the granularity of predictions wanted, ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - Am a noob. So, please bear with me. I would like to know what will be reason for the patient's next hospitalization (time of which I will predict). I don't know what more information to add in the question..example : Patient_id 123 next hospitalization date might be 21st Jan 2022 and he has 70% chance of visiting for eye complication due to diabetes etc

Comment: Hi @forecaster - Are you saying that the `reason` for the patient's next hospital admission can be inferred from the `risk factors that influence the hospital admission`?

Comment: How many different reasons for hospitalization do you want to discriminate between? And, for what use? Maybe which hospital department they will need? Emergency room, internal medicin, ... ? or some other? How big data base?

Comment: Okay. Let's current focus on `hypertension` patients. We have lot of hypertension complications such as `Heart attack or stroke`, `Aneurysm` or `Metabolic syndrome` etc. Our data may also have this complication information because in our hospital database we have recorded patient's encounters/consultations with clinicians/lab values/ drugs prescribed etc. We have inpatient, Outpatient and emergency visits.. We have around 5000 Hypertension patients

Comment: We choose complications of hypertension because our population is hypertension patients. It is known/obvious that they more chance for visiting hospital for treating complications that develop due to hypertension. If they have some totally unrelated disease, of course we will not be able to predict that (because whatever we learnt from data is based on patient's past data based on hypertension). So anything unrelated can't be predicted. Do you agree with me on this?

Comment: @TheGreat I think what you are looking is longitudinal data analysis. If you have cross sectional data, it would predict what the risk factors for next(new) patient, but if you are looking at for a patient what is the likelihood of **readmission**.

Comment: @forecaster Yes, I have to do longitudinal data analysis. you are right that I would need to find a likelihood of readmission. But along with that, I would also like to find why will he be readmitted? ex: Patient 123 has 70% chance of readmission on 21st Jan 2022 with 80% likelihood of eye complication due to diabetes.

Comment: @forecaster - I am still trying to formulate this problem. Is there any paper or tutorial that you can share if you have time? I am basically trying to do two tasks, a) Predict the time for next hospitalization b) Predict the reason for next hospitalization... Ex: `Patient 123 has 70% chance of readmission by 21st May 2022 with 80% likelihood of heart complication due to hypertension`. The above example is inferred based on our dataset which has hypertension patients